# What exactly is a safe method in REST web services?

Tags: web-services, rest

I am absolutly new in REST and I have the following doubt about what are **safe method** in REST and what are **idempotent method**.

I know (but it could be wrong) that GET, HEAD, OPTIONS and TRACE methods are defined as safe because they are only intended for retrieving data.

But now I am reading this article: http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/idempotency/ and it say that:

> Safe methods are HTTP methods that do not modify resources. For
>   instance, using GET or HEAD on a resource URL, should NEVER change the
>   resource.

And untill here it is ok, it is nothing different from what I yek know, but after it assert that:

> However, this is not completely true. It means: it won't change the
>   resource representation. It is still possible, that safe methods do
>   change things on a server or resource, but this should not reflect
>   in a different representation.

What exactly means this assertion? What exactly is a representation? and what means that a safe method so change on a resource but that this change is not refleted into a different representation?

Then it does also this example:

```
GET /blog/1234/delete HTTP/1.1
```

and say that it is incorrect if this would actually delete the blogpost and assert that:

> Safe methods are methods that can be cached, prefetched without any
>   repercussions to the resource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What exactly is a representation?

A "representation" is the data that is returned from the server that represents the state of the object.  So if you GET at http://server/puppy/1 it should return a "representation" of the puppy (because, it can't return the *actual* puppy of course.)

> > However, this is not completely true. It means: it won't change the
> >     resource representation. It is still possible, that safe methods do
> >     change things on a server or resource, but this should not reflect in
> >     a different representation.
>
> What exactly means this assertion?

They mean that if you GET /server/puppy/1 two times in a row, it should give you the same response.  However, imagine you have a field that contains the number of times each puppy was viewed.  That field is used to provide a page listing the top 10 most viewed puppies.  That information is provided via GET /server/puppystats.  It is okay for GET /server/puppy/1 to update that information.  But it should not update information about the puppy itself.  Or, if it DOES update the information about the puppy itself, that information is not part of the representation of the puppy returned by GET /server/puppy/1.  It is only part of some other representation that is available via another URL.

If it helps, this is a similar concept to the "mutable" keyword in C++ when applied to a const object.  "mutable" allows you to modify the object, but it should not modify it in a way that is visible outside of the class.

Comment: So about representation I an say that a JSON and an XML returned date of the state of my puppy object (associated to the id=1) are 2 differents representation of the same data?

Comment: I don't know.  I was thinking that a different representation would be a different set of fields that refer to the same object.  But, maybe changing the encoding is considered a different representation too.